# How to use JSON retrieved from Webserver in Java Android App to create and use Objects dynamically

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I am building a Java Android App with Webserver (Raspberry Pi 4 with LAMP) connection for the first time.

There's a db table "products" which holds all products (Product_id, productName, price). I am retrieving a JSON array though a PHP API.

On App launch, I want to get all products and create Java Objects out of them, so I can dynamically display all products and prices in a Fragment in my app. Note that number and price of products might change, so I need this approach to dynamically create the products.

Since I have never done this before, I am stuck. I know how to get a response in my code, but what I need help with is to turn that response into Java Objects. Any advice how you usually would do that?

Here's my JSON:

```
"status": 200,
"info": [
    {
        "Product_id": "1",
        "product": "Coca Cola",
        "price": "3"
    },
    {
        "Product_id": "2",
        "product": "Orange Juice",
        "price": "2.5"
    },
    {
        "Product_id": "3",
        "product": "Apple Juice",
        "price": "2.5"
    },
    {
        "Product_id": "4",
        "product": "Beer",
        "price": "1.5"
    },
    {
        "Product_id": "5",
        "product": "Energy Drink",
        "price": "3"
    },
    {
        "Product_id": "6",
        "product": "Gin Tonic",
        "price": "5"
    },
    {
        "Product_id": "7",
        "product": "Water",
        "price": "1"
    },
    {
        "Product_id": "8",
        "product": "Soda",
        "price": "1"
    },
    {
        "Product_id": "9",
        "product": "Ticket",
        "price": "30"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you want to deserialize your json into your data model to handle dynamically, then you can use Gson library:  YourData yourData = Gson().fromJson(json, YourData.class); And that´s all, now you have a yourData object.

Comment: Use `Gson` map your response json to Java object. [Gson](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-parse-json-with-gson/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used Gson, as Manuel and Ibrahim suggested. Thank you!